# Change DragShadowBuilder while dragging (Android)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to change the border of the drag image color to red while the drag image is being dragged to the left and blue if being dragged to the right. No not after the drag but while dragging. Is this possible? What I'am talking about is changing the DragShadowBuilder image while dragging. I have this code:

```
drop.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            Float y1 = event.getX();
            Float x1 = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // Do nothing
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    x1 =  event.getX();
                    y1 =  event.getY();
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d("msg", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    cView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Float x2 = event.getX();
                    Float y2 = event.getY();
                    if (x2 > x1) {
                        cView.setBorderColor(Integer.parseInt("2E4172", 16) + 0xFF000000);
                        cView.setShadowColor(Integer.parseInt("4F628E", 16) + 0xFF000000);
                    } else {
                        cView.setBorderColor(Integer.parseInt("AA3939", 16) + 0xFF000000);
                        cView.setShadowColor(Integer.parseInt("D46A6A", 16) + 0xFF000000);
                    }
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    // Do nothing
                    cView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Do nothing
                    Log.d("Drop Location", Float.toString(event.getX()) + " : " + Float.toString(event.getY()));
                    cView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String direction = new String();
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();
                    if (x2 > x1) {
                        direction = "right";
                    } else {
                        direction = "left";
                    }

                    Log.d("Going to Directon", direction);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    cView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("Motion Action", event.toString());
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(cView);
                    cView.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, cView, 0);
                    cView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```